# Regex one digit repeated more than n times in line with grep

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I need to find the regex expression to find a same digit that repeats 4 or more times with grep.

for example valid match will be

**1**exampl**1**of**1**val3id**1**match**1**

**22**ad//13sf**2**qett**2222**

**3333**asdfccwerq**3**w+134er

What I tried was

```
grep -E '[1-9]{4,}' filename
```

Comment: `grep -E '([0-9])(.*\1){3}' filename`?

Comment: Same question? [How can I satisfy the following conditions using the grep command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62227852/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
grep -E '([0-9])(.*\1){3}' filename
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bqR2PC/1/)

**Details**

- `([0-9])` - Group 1: a digit
- `(.*\1){3}` - Three repetitions of any 0 or more characters followed with the same digit as captured in Group 1.

Comment: may i ask why is it {3} not {4}? I thought (.*\1){3} means group1  x 3, is it something like group1 +(group1 x 3) ?

Comment: @goldenasian You want to get all lines that contain 4 or more (=at least 4) occurrences of the same digit, right? `([0-9])` matches 1, `(.*\1){3}` matches 3. 1+3=4.